# How to pass an object as a parameter with MVC Web Api GET

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

In MVC, when I post, I can pass a json object to my MVC controller. I am guessing, behind the scenes, MVC maps the property values by property name.

I am trying this with get.

This works fine with POST

The URL

```
"/api/myapi/?request=" + JSON.stringify(myJsonObj
```

with the API defined as

```
[HttpPost]
public MyResponse Comparison(MyRequest request)
```

Now, I want to change it to GET

URL

```
"/api/myapi/?request=" + JSON.stringify(myJsonObj
```

with the API defined as

```
[HttpGet]
public MyResponse Comparison(MyRequest request)
```

If I update to

```
[HttpGet]
public MyResponse Comparison([FromQuery] MyRequest request)
```

then the end point is hit, but every property in `request` is null

The reason, in case of XY, is although I could achieved this with a querystring and multiple input parameters on my Controller, it would mean I would have to manually create the `MyRequest` object for each point - I am lazy and I want to use the automagic of MVC serialisation so I don't need to serailise in every end point.

Comment: Can you show your whole javasctipt  code including myJsonObj, pls?

Comment: You can know more about what model binding is, how it works, and how to customize its behavior from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Yup. Searching the docs is always easier when you know the terms... I didn't even think of the words model binding, I was thinking of it as "passing". Thank you for the link, I will do some extra reading!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fix, to pass a complex object into a GET end point/controller is

Within Javascript, the URL I pass is

> /api/myapi/?para1=1&para2=hello&para3=2021-09-09"

and the End Point is

```
[HttpGet]
public MyResponse Comparison([FromQuery] MyRequest request)
```

And the definition of `MyRequest` is

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int para1 {get;set;}
    public string para2 {get;set;}
    public string para3 {get;set;}
}
```